# "I want to come there" or "I want to go there"

Tags: word-choice, verbs

When someone is away from you and wants to be where you are, do they tell you *I want to come there* or *I want to go there*?

Answer (score 6):

I have always thought that *go* has a slight connotational leaning to describing the journey, or leaving the origin.
*Come* has a connotation to arriving, or the destination.

Thus, "I want to *go* to Paris" states that I want to make a journey, with Paris as the destination, but that the journey is important.

"I want to *come* to Rome" implies that the arrival in Rome is for a specific reason that is personally, emotionally important to the speaker.

Moreover, *coming* to Rome, as opposed to *going* to Paris, seems to imply that the speaker is addressing someone who is in Rome, and will be *coming* to them or *going* to Paris.

I believe that both choices are grammatically valid, but that each has a slightly different meaning invested in it.

Comment: Actually, _go_ doesn't have the connotation of leaving the origin, and _come_ the connotation of arriving to the destination. Compare _Jennifer went home_ with _Jennifer came home_, or _Jessica came into the kitchen_ with _Jessica went into the kitchen_. None of the sentences speaks of where the person was before moving; they all say where the person arrived. The difference between _come_ and _go_ is another one.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I disagree - *Jennifer went home* is closer than *Jennifer came home* to *Jennifer left*. I agree with Carmi's sense that *go* has a "slight connotation" with the departure and *come*, with the arrival.

Comment: @Lawrence In both the sentences it's implicit that Jennifer moved from a place, or it would not be travelling. There is something else that makes the difference between _Jennifer went home_ and _Jennifer came home_.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, when speaking with a person that is away from you, *I want to come there* would be understood as *I want to travel and arrive where you are*.

*I want to go there* could mean *I want to go in the place we are talking of*.

Comment: 'I want to come there' is correct because it references the location of _the person being addressed_.

Answer (score 1):

The most common/natural expression here is probably along the lines of:

> I wish I were there.

(Okay, so many people don't bother to use the subjunctive - as you should - and say *was* instead of *were*.)

A possible alternative is *I want to be there* - it's slightly less natural sounding to me though, at least in British English.

*I want to go there.* might be an appropriate response if someone mentioned a foreign country/holiday destination that sounded appealing to you. I can't think of any real-word situation in which *I want to come there.* would sound best.

Comment: "I wish I were there" is expressing a wish for having been there *now*. It's not equivalent to "I want to come/go there". (As in: "Will you be in Vienna another two months? I want to come there in the summer.")

Comment: Or even "That place you're describing sounds wonderful! I want to buy tickets and come there right now". In both examples, the OP is asking whether "go" would be right in place of "come".

Comment: "That place you're describing sounds wonderful!" would be quite unnatural in (British) English - a bit convoluted. Otherwise, yeah. I just thought I'd point out alternative contexts in which it makes more sense. :)

Comment: _I want to go there_ doesn't necessarily mean I am talking of a foreign country. I could be speaking of an event happening in my country with a person living in the same building I live, and say _I want to go there_ to mean _I want to go to the event we are speaking of_. When speaking to a person that doesn't live where I live, _I want to come there_ could mean _I want to travel and arrive where you are_.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to say that there is a fairly simple and straightforward rule to this confusion.  If you are presently at the location, then use "come" (as in: While sitting at a cafe in Rome drinking espresso "I would love to come back next year." or alternatively, "Excuse me, can you come over here").  But, if you are not presently at the location, to use "go" (as in: "Will you go over there." or "Hawai'i? I would love to go there.").

Comment: That’s all well and good as a first approximation, but your rule doesn’t take into account the possibility that you are talking to somebody who is not located where you are, and you are discussing travel to the other person’s location. For example (phoning home from the office): “Sorry I had to work late; I’m coming home now.” Or (e.g., when rescuing an injured person): “Stay where you are; I’ll come to you.”